# How do we pass an argument to a Python script (unstructured format code) on the command line in an?

Tags: python, runtime

I'm going to ask a strange question.  I write approximately 800 lines of code. Now I need to specify different batch sizes and evaluate my model's results. One method is to manually adjust the batch size, which I am already doing.

However, if I send my script file to a user and instruct them to manually set the batch size, this may be very inconvenient. A more accurate method is to specify the batch size at run time with a script file passed as an argument on the command line.

However, I did not formally write code (in functions). It is largely unstructured. Then how do I transfer the batch size via script file at run time? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do this in python is using the inbuilt **sys** module.

#### How to pass arguments through command line

`python myCoolModel.py 200`

this way you can send batch size to your python function

#### How to use arguments passed through the command line

```py
import sys
 
if len(sys.argv) != 2:   # System taking 2 if argument is passed with script name
    batch_size = 500 #your predefined batch size in case if user doesn't send one
else:
    batch_size = sys.argv[0] #Reading from passed command line arguments
 
print(f'Batch Size is {batch_size}')
```